# Highcharts points and lines are missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

This is the code generated by highcharts for lines and point. I'm using inspect element and points are where they should be but they seem to be transparent or something like behind he chart. but the code looks right.

```
    <g class="highcharts-series-group" zIndex="3">
    <g class="highcharts-series" clip-path="url(http://localhost:63540/admin/reports.aspx?type=like#highcharts-1)" visibility="visible" transform="translate(40,10)">
    <path d="M 244 50.4 L 732 302.6" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="5" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.05" transform="translate(1,1)"></path>
    <path d="M 244 50.4 L 732 302.6" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="3" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.1" transform="translate(1,1)"></path>
    <path d="M 244 50.4 L 732 302.6" fill="none" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1" isShadow="true" stroke-opacity="0.15000000000000002" transform="translate(1,1)"></path>
<path d="M 244 50.4 L 732 302.6" fill="none" stroke="#4D4D4D" stroke-width="2"></path><path d="M 732 298.6 C 737.328 298.6 737.328 306.6 732 306.6 C 726.672 306.6 726.672 298.6 732 298.6 Z" fill="#4D4D4D" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.000001" zIndex="2000"></path>
    <path d="M 244 46.4 C 249.328 46.4 249.328 54.4 244 54.4 C 238.672 54.4 238.672 46.4 244 46.4 Z" fill="#4D4D4D" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.000001"></path></g></g>
```

What can be wrong with it? 
It's funny that I have copied the code from my other project (that is working) and only have changed the data.

this is the compiled js code:

```
   var dates = ['1394/12/06','1394/12/11'];
    after.push(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    height: 500,
                    backgroundColor:'#eee',
                    renderTo: 'chart',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                    // marginRight: 130,

                    //marginBottom: 150,
                   // marginTop: 20,
                   // events: { click: function () { startWait($('html')); document.location = 'price.aspx' } }
                },
                title: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: dates,
                    labels: {
                        rotation: 90,
                        formatter: function () {
                            return this.value;
                        },
                        y:40
                    }

                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }],
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                         //   return toFarsi(virgulize(this.value)) ;
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return "<b>" + this.y + "</b>";
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    //enabled: false
                },
series: [

                {
                    name:' likes',
                    color:'#4D4D4D',
                    data: [2,1]
                },

]
            });
        });
```

Comment: It seems to work fine, as is: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/54upcw1d/  Can you reproduce the problem in the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after disabling css, javascript, and many other tests nothing worked.
Thanks to  jlbriggs his fiddle gave me the idea of testing the code with older version of jquery.

It worked with older version of jquery.

**Update:**
New version of Highcharts works with the latest version of jquery.